# How to Add Multiple websites to Google Places with single address?

Tags: seo, google

Currently I have five different-different location based websites but i have only oine physical address so how can i verify 5 google pages for all website with single address.

P.S.
i need to use same business name, phone number and address.

Comment: Asking SEO questions and having a username like SEO Master tend not to go hand in hand.

Comment: @JohnConde lol i almost spit coffee on my keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

**In short, you cant** unless you try to sneak through Googles spam/duplicate filters, or get on the good side of one of the Google "places for business" moderators.

After speaking with a guy named John at Google maps for an hour or so, it was clear that they manually procure the Google places. They automate it too, so that is why you see insta-warnings about duplicate listings when a property is too similar.

Example: We have 3 sites on the same physical location. They are all niche stores of a total inventory of the brick N mortar. Different names, different contact points, different reach, but same address/phone. They exist without duplicate, but when John saw this he was very worried we would be punished by the automated checks. Thankfully he used manual intervention to attempt to "lock it in"...meaning it would be more resilient to the anti-spam automation, but he also said there are no guarantees how long that will last. Apparently they are changing the places/maps a bunch lately.

So if you make your sites unique enough from each other and use a different name it might work. If you continue to do what you do (same biz name, same site, same everything) it may never allow you to register the duplicates it finds.